# Protect desktop application images from external modification

Tags: java

I am developing a standalone desktop application in SWT which makes use of several images.

These images are included in my application's directory structure. So, just to make a silly example, anyone could replace my logo with theirs, claim the application as their work and brag with friends.

What is the most efficient way to prevent people from modifying or stealing the images used in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can make it harder (add the logo to the jar, use encryption, sign jars etc.) but AFAIK you cannot prevent it.

Legally: make clear under what license you distribute your application and what your trademarks are.

Answer (score 1):

You can embbed them in a JAR file but it is still possible to change them.

You can try to encode the file as Base64 and put the result in a String class member, and when you need it you decode the String (quick but very dirty). It is still possible to decompile the class and change the content but it is harder.

There is no magic solution, unfortunately.